# Emacs weird line movement

Tags: emacs

new to emacs. I'm trying to work on my React project however every time I go to a new line it moves the line above back. I'm really not totally sure what I'm doing with emacs yet so forgive me! Any advice or help on how to fix this?

[Here is the problem with it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uAcOF.png)

Comment: You mean it reindents the line on cursor movement? Or when you type something (what?)

Comment: For this kind of issue, it is more useful to share a gif rather than a screenshot. What you want to highlight is the movement (reindentation) that happens when you hit enter, but that is lost in the image. Also, you can embed your image in the post itself ;)

Comment: @elethan Sorry, I'm new to all this :) I was planning on making it a gif but I had no clue how to haha!

Comment: @JoshuaEttinger no problem! Just trying to give you some tips! We were all there once ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To try to recreate your issue, I tried editing a react file, and found the same behavior if I am using `javascript-mode`, which it appears from your screenshot is what you are using.

To see what emacs was doing, I did `M-x describe-key` (which is `C-h k` for me) and hit the enter key, and got this:

```
RET (translated from <return>) runs the command newline (found in
global-map), which is an interactive compiled Lisp function in
‘simple.el’.

It is bound to RET.

(newline &optional ARG INTERACTIVE)

Insert a newline, and move to left margin of the new line if it’s blank.
If option ‘use-hard-newlines’ is non-nil, the newline is marked with the
text-property ‘hard’.
With ARG, insert that many newlines.

If ‘electric-indent-mode’ is enabled, this indents the final new line
that it adds, and reindents the preceding line.  To just insert
a newline, use M-x electric-indent-just-newline.
```

I think this is the part that is relevant to what you are seeing (emphasis mine):

> If ‘electric-indent-mode’ is enabled, this indents the final new line
>   that it adds, and **reindents the preceding line**.

I also do some react in emacs. In my experience, the default `javascript-mode`, or even some of the more advanced Javascript modes (like [`js2-mode`](https://elpa.gnu.org/packages/js2-mode.html)) do not play particularly well with React's JSX syntax. The best thing I have found so far is [`rjsx-mode`](https://github.com/felipeochoa/rjsx-mode). You might give that a try! I think with that mode enabled, you will find that indentation behave much more sensibly in JSX blocks.

Comment: Thank you for posting! This is super! The electric indent did the trick.